# render view after a post request in react/redux

Tags: reactjs, onclick, redux, state, rerender

I have post method helper where I'm making the rest calls to the server which is basically running but the view/container is not rerendering after the call.

```
export function postData(action, errorType, isAuthReq, url, dispatch, data) {
  const requestUrl = API_URL + url;
  let headers = {};

  if (isAuthReq) {
    headers = {headers: {'Authorization': cookie.load('token')}};
  }

  axios.post(requestUrl, data, headers)
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({
        type: action,
        payload: response.data
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      errorHandler(dispatch, error.response, errorType)
    });
}
```

I'm getting the the following error: **`dispatch is not defined` in the browser when I'm calling this method**

my call from the container is as followed:

```
handleFavorite(buildingId) {
  const url = `/building/${buildingId}/toogle-favorite`;
  postData(FETCH_All_BUILDING, AUTH_ERROR, true, url, this.props.dispatch, {});
}
```

This is how my connect method is looks like:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    buildings: state.building.buildings,
    error: state.building.error,
    userId: state.auth.userId
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {buildingsAll})(BuildingAll);
```

#### My Question is...

How can I re render my view? This dispatch that I want to give to the method is not available. Is there a possibility to bind that rest to the state perhaps with `mapDispatchToProps`. Any idea how I can solve that problem, I'm fairly new to react/redux - it's my first side project in that lib.

Thanks

#### Update 1

I have updated the code but getting the next error and my view is now not rendering (nothing showing).

```
mapDispatchToProps() in Connect(BuildingAll) must return a plain object. Instead received function 
bundle.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: finalMergeProps is not a function

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators(postDataThunk, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, {buildingsAll})(BuildungAll);
```

Comment: Have you looked at redux-thunk? You're possibly having issues because you're sending an async request, which is something that can redux thunk can fully utilize

Comment: I'm already using redux-thunk in some of my request

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your action creators in your container

```
const { bindActionCreators } = require("redux");

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        buildings: state.building.buildings,
        error: state.building.error,
        userId: state.auth.userId
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators(YourActions, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BuildingAll);
```

And then your action becomes something like this:

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const postData = (action, errorType, isAuthReq, url, data) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const requestUrl = API_URL + url;
        let headers = {};

        if (isAuthReq) {
            headers = { headers: { 'Authorization': cookie.load('token') } };
        }

        axios.post(requestUrl, data, headers)
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: action,
                    payload: response.data
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                errorHandler(dispatch, error.response, errorType)
            });
    };
};
```

Because your postData might have a few side effects because it's fetching something asynchronously, you'll need a thunk

Read this article on it: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Comment: I'have updated my code but I'm getting not the error s. **Update 1** section